# best way to display multi-columned data in grid format in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, datagridview

What is the best way to display multi-columned data in a grid format using C# WinForms?

Is it ListView or DataGridView?

Comment: Are you talking WinForms or ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) is your best bet for simple grid display. However, if you are needing nested (collapsible/expandable) display for child rows, etc. DataGridView will not do that.

The [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) would be good for something like the way Windows Explorer displays objects, properties, files, etc.

Answer (score 1):

datagridview is the choice , its shows data in grid format, also supports operation like sorting, filtering which is required by lot of apps nowadays

Comment: Is there a reason why you recommend the [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.aspx) over the [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx)? Both are still supported, I'm just curious why you think the `DataGrid` is better suited to this task.

Comment: Updated my answer , i have written this answer from my ipad in hurry so missed view in datagrid